# Cheap PoE board with TCP/IP support

Tags: hardware, microcontrollers, ethernet

I have a small IoT project where I want a network enabled electrical relay. I do not need full network plug nor linux on it. It just should be small and cheap. I feel smart enough to write a small http server in C/C++ (if required) to change the state of the relay. I searched of cause the web and found the almost matching dublicate [Cheap IoT microcontroller with PoE](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/cheap-iot-microcontroller-with-poe)

However this is much bigger then what I have in mind. I want a small board with 6 skews to mount the wires (2 or more replays would be fine too). I want to control a device for with less then 25V (I'm not sure but very likely 12V DC). However I do not want to write the TCP/IP stack by my own.

Any ideas?

Comment: This might almost be better asked at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ However, the TCP stack makes it eligible here.  There's a lot of crossover, so if you don't get an answer here, try there after a week or so.

Comment: Can you help us by defining "small" and "cheap"? These are relative terms. ***Must*** it be POE? Would you accept WiFi, with a power source (USB or other)? Is the power for the controlled device also coming from the board which you seek?

Comment: I bought already a POE switch for a different device and I have there no room for more cables. Cheap let's say less then 50€ it should the longest side should be smaller then 55mm including an case if required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I am a big fan of the [Omega 2](https://onion.io/omega2/), which is not much bigger than a full size SIM card or SD card. It runs Linux, so there is your TCP/IP stack.

[image]

It has a good spec and will set you back a whopping $13.

> ```
> 580MHz MIPS CPU
> 128MB Memory
> 32MB Storage
> USB2.0 support
> 2.4GHz b/g/n WiFi
> 3.3V Operating Voltage
> 18 GPIOs
> Support for UART, I2C, SPI
> MicroSD slot
> ```

Just by coincidence, I received their newsletter about 20 minutes ago and it describes [a PoE project](https://onion.io/2bt-june-12-2018/).

That will set you back another few bucks, so I will leave it to you to decide if it is "cheap". Hope this helps.